# flutter: how to customize CupertinoAlertDialog's width and height?

Tags: flutter, dialog

I'm working with flutter. I want to make a CupertinoAlertDialog(iOS style is required). The problem is UI designer require the width and height respectfully are 270 and 140. I have searched in the flutter doc but could not find related property. Is that possible? Thanks for any advice. The basic code I completed is placed below.

```
              showCupertinoDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context){
                  return Theme(
                    data: ThemeData.dark(),
                    child: CupertinoAlertDialog(
                      title: Text('Title'),
                      content: Text('Some message here'),
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: Text('Cancle'),
                        ),
                        FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: Text('OK'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }
              );
```

Comment: As far as I see is no. There is no width or height property in `CupertinoAlertDialog`. You may need to create your dialog with specific size. Another hacker is wrap the `CupertinoAlertDialog` with `Center` and `SizedBox`. But you still need to concern the padding/margin in  `CupertinoAlertDialog` (You can turn on Debug Paint to see. The outer padding is (40,24,40,24) and inner margin is (0,20,0,20))

Comment: @yellowgray thanks for your advice. Maybe I should customize a dialog.